# let $k$ be a positive divisor of $q-1$ and $a\in F_q$ be such that the equation $x^k=a$ has no solution in $F_q$...

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields, extension-field, splitting-field

let $k$ be a positive divisor of $q-1$ and $a\in F_q$ be such that the equation $x^k=a$ has no solution in $F_q$. Prove that the same equation has a solution in $F_{q^m}$ if $m$ is divisible by $k$, and that the converse holds for a prime number $k$.

Try using the hypotheses to build the solution, for example: as $ k | q-1 $ so in $ F_q ^ * $ there exists $ \beta $ such that $ \beta ^ k = 1 $ ... but the truth is that I do not know what to do. Help me please.

Comment: Your previous questions were closed.. You have to make clear what you (don't) know and what you tried.

Comment: Try using the hypotheses to build the solution, for example: as $k|q−1$ so in $F_q^*$ there exists $\beta$ such that $\beta^k=1$ ... but the truth is that I do not know what to do. Help me please.

Comment: What happens if $a$ has order $q-1$ and $x^k=a$, what is the order of $x$ ?

Comment: if $ord(a)=q-1$ then $x^{k(q-1)}=1$, so $ord(x)=k(q-1)$...  but I want to prove that $ ord (x) = q ^ m-1 $, and so $ x \in F_{q ^ m} $

Comment: Can you make your argument rigorous that $x$ has order $k(q-1)$ ? (ie. $x^{k(q-1)}=1=1$ and $x^l\ne 1$ for $l | k(q-1)$). Next can $x$ be in $F_q$ ? What is the least $m$ such that $x\in F_{q^m}$ ?

Comment: $ord(x)=k(q-1)$ because $ord(a)=q-1$, so no $ l $ less than $ k (q-1) $ can be the order of $ x $ since otherwise $ a ^ l = 1 $ and $ l <q-1 $. And $ x $ cannot be in $ F_q $ since the equation $ x ^ k = a $ has no solutions in $ F_q $ ... I'm trying to see the last part, but I can't get it yet.

Comment: If $x$ has order $k(q-1)$ then it generates a group with $k(q-1)$ elements. $F_q$ has only $q-1$ elements.